# C# How to modify xml attributes based on searched string

Tags: c#, xml, iteration

I want to find all instances of an element attribute that contains a certain string and change it.

Sample xml would be:

```
<system>
  <template>
    <url address="http://localhost:7888/Application/basic" />
    <url address="http://localhost:7997/sdk/basic" />
    <url address="http://localhost:5855/htm/ws" />
    <url address="net.tcp://localhost:5256/htm" />
    <url address="http://localhost:5215/htm/basic" />
    <url address="http://localhost:5235/htm/ws" />
    <url address="net.tcp://localhost:5256/htm" />
    <url address="http://localhost:5252/Projectappmgr/basic"/>
    <url address="http://localhost:5295/Projectappmgr/ws" />
  </template>
</system>
```

I have the following code:

```
XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.GetElementsByTagName("url");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
{
    if (node.Attributes["address"].Value.Contains("localhost"))
    {
        string origValue = node.Attributes["address"].Value;
        string modValue = String.Empty;
        Console.WriteLine("Value of original address is: " + origValue);
        modValue = origValue.Replace("localhost", "newURLName");
        Console.WriteLine("Value of modified address is: " + modValue);
        node.Attributes["address"].InnerText = modValue;
    }
}
```

This modifies the address' value as expected.

```
<url address="http://newURLName:7888/Application/basic" />
```

But, what I really want is to replace the entire string "localhost:7888" with `newURLName`.  Is there a way to specify the port numbers as wild characters since they will not all be the same as in the example xml block?

I know I need the replace value to be "localhost:xxxx", but "xxxx" is different in each instance and I'm sort of drawing a blank at the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions should help here:

```
  modValue = Regex.Replace(url, @"localhost(:\d+){0,1}", newUrlName)
```

[Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html) you can find more exapmles. Also I would recommend using [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) to get familiar with Regex.

Comment: Thank You for the links.  Just had to correct the escape sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You could use xpath to find nodes which contain your *search string* and then use [`UriBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) class to modify your URLs:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var nodes = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//url[contains(@address, 'localhost')]");
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    var ub = new UriBuilder(node.Attribute("address").Value);
    ub.Host = "newURLName";
    node.SetAttributeValue("address", ub.ToString());
}
```

This will get you

```
<system>
  <template>
    <url address="http://newURLName:7888/Application/basic" />
    <url address="http://newURLName:7997/sdk/basic" />
    <url address="http://newURLName:5855/htm/ws" />
    <url address="net.tcp://newURLName:5256/htm" />
    <url address="http://newURLName:5215/htm/basic" />
    <url address="http://newURLName:5235/htm/ws" />
    <url address="net.tcp://newURLName:5256/htm" />
    <url address="http://newURLName:5252/Projectappmgr/basic" />
    <url address="http://newURLName:5295/Projectappmgr/ws" />
  </template>
</system>
```

from your XML example even without [using of regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/102112).

Comment: Great minds and all that. One thing I wasn't sure of without playing is can you set the host and port number at the same time by setting the host name with a string that contains the hostname and the portnumber i.e. uriBuilder.Host = "newhost:80";

Comment: @Bronumski, nope. It'll threat `hewhost:portnumber` as a *host* only; so the previous portnumber will be appended like this: `http://[newURLName:777]:7888/Application/basic`.

Comment: Shame, always looking for the one liner. Thanks for the feedback though.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
modValue = origValue.Replace("localhost", "newURLName");
```

by

```
modValue = Regex.Replace(origValue, "localhost(:[0-9]+){0,1}", "newURLName");
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to regex would be to use a strongly typed [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) object and the [UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx).

```cs
var origValue = new Uri(node.Attributes["address"].Value);

var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(origValue);
uriBuilder.Host = newHost;
uriBuilder.Port = newPort;

modValue = uriBuilder.Uri;
```

This may seem long winded but it is an alternative to a simple regex, gives you something that is strongly typed and allows you to validate that the Uri is actually valid (see the Uri class methods / properties). You may also be able to do the host and port number in one step, I have not played around with that.

Comment: Thanks.  New to programming.  Have not dealt with Uri, but will definitely look into it.